# Microservice returning 405 after going through Zuul gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following setup: an authentication service (which uses JWT), a Zuul API gateway and a QR code service. Whenever I test the follow flow locally:

With username and password as body:

```
localhost:8762/api/auth-service/auth/
```

I get the Bearer token and use it to access the QR code service:

I use the text in the body and it's a POST request which returns the QR image.

```
localhost:8762/api/qr-service/qr-codes/
```

However, when I try this in my staging environment in Portainer I get the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-07T13:16:59.188+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/qr-codes/"
}
```

Somehow, by the time it gets to the QR service, it has changed to a GET request since the output logs show this:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add `https://` to the staging environment request.